# React audio Cannot set property 'volume' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I am trying to play an mp3 using the Audio element but whenever the player renders an error occurs:- Cannot set property 'volume' of undefined.

Play prop is just a boolean value.

The useRef() current property shows me the mp3 file when I console.log it.

I removed the volume property but then it displays the same error for audio.play().

why is the audio undefined?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "../../Static/player.css";
import Nowplaying from "./Nowplaying";
import SongInfo from "./SongInfo";
import Slider from "./Slider";
import Duration from "./Duration";
import song from "../../Static/assets/song.mp3";

const Player = (props) => {

  const { Play } = props;

  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0)
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0)
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0)

  const audioRef = useRef()


  const onChange = (e) => {
    const audio = audioRef.current
    audio.currentTime = (audio.duration / 100) * e.target.value
    setPercentage(e.target.value)
  }


  const play = () => {
    const audio = audioRef.current
    audio.volume = 0.1

    if (!Play) {
      audio.play()
    }

    if (Play) {
      audio.pause()
    }
  }

  const getCurrDuration = (e) => {
    const percent = ((e.currentTarget.currentTime / e.currentTarget.duration) * 100).toFixed(2)
    const time = e.currentTarget.currentTime

    setPercentage(+percent)
    setCurrentTime(time.toFixed(2))
  }

  if (Play) {
    play();
  } else {
    play();
  }

  return (
    <div className="player-screen">
      <div className="play-screen">
        <div className="navbar">
          <Nowplaying />
        </div>
        <div className="song-info">
          <SongInfo />
        </div>
        <div className="player-controls">
          <Slider percentage={percentage} onChange={onChange} />
          <Duration
            duration={duration}
            currentTime={currentTime}
          />
          <audio
            ref={audioRef}
            onTimeUpdate={getCurrDuration}
            onLoadedData={(e) => {
              setDuration(e.currentTarget.duration.toFixed(2));
            }}
            src={song}
          ></audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

what wrong am I doing?

Comment: Please add a check to make sure `audio` is not null. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element specifically the part which says _"React will assign the current property with the DOM element when the component mounts, and assign it back to null when it unmounts"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code:

```js
  if (Play) {
    play();
  } else {
    play();
  }
```

gets immediately called, before React even has the chance to set `audioRef.current` to the Audio element. *Your function hasn't even finished rendering yet, React doesn't even know where `audioRef` is used.*

Move that piece of code into a `useEffect`, or better yet, replace your `audioRef` with a callback function (which can still store the Audio element in another ref or state variable), as shown [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Comment: Thanks it worked, I am new to react. you are correct function is called before it renders and that is why it worked when I put the code when it was already rendered but gave an error when I refreshed it. Thanks.